# Default Value in ModelForm from Database

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a ModelForm in my Django App which should always display the latest given Option as default Input in the form but it's not working:

models.py

```
from django.db import models

Anmeldung = (
    ('1', 'Ja'),
    ('2', 'Nein'),
    ('3', 'Noch nicht entschieden'),
)

Essen = (
    ('1', 'Fleisch'),
    ('2', 'Fisch'),
    ('3', 'Vegetarisch'),
)

class Eintrag(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Anmeldung = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=Anmeldung,
        default=Eintrag.objects.filter(Name=request.user).Anmeldung # Thats not working
    Essen = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=Essen,
        default=1)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
```

Only one row per user is in the data so that should not be a problem. 
How do I achieve this? Is models.py even the right place or do I have to write this into the views or form part?

forms.py and models.py if it helps:

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Eintrag

class NameForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
            model = Eintrag
            fields = ['Anmeldung', 'Essen']
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

from .forms import NameForm
from .models import Eintrag

@login_required()
def get_name(request):

    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = NameForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            Eintrag.objects.filter(Name=request.user).delete()
            eintrag = form.save(commit=False)
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            # ...
            # redirect to a new URL:
            eintrag.Name = request.user  # Set the user object here
            eintrag.pub_date = timezone.now()  # Set the user object here
            eintrag.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path)  # generate an empty form

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = NameForm()

    posts = Eintrag.objects.filter(Name=request.user)
    return render(request, 'form/name.html', {'form': form, 'posts': posts})
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: I wonder if everything worked fine because in models you have used request.user but there is no request variable.

Comment: the recent option chosen by a user or, just the latest option in the these tuples ; `Anmeldung = (
    ('1', 'Ja'),
    ('2', 'Nein'),
    ('3', 'Noch nicht entschieden'),
)`

Comment: @SHIVAMJINDAL yes actually, here is how he tried to have the default value, it will never work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show default value in form only, you should set default value in form. Use below code in views.py and remove default value from models

```
form = NameForm()
form.fields['Anmeldung'].initial = Eintrag.objects.filter(Name=request.user).last().Anmeldung
```